# OpenMP - Iterator in the For-loop

Tags: iterator, for-loop, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+ : numOfVecs)
for(itc=clus.begin() ; itc!=clus.end() ; itc++)
{
    numOfVecs += (*itc)->getNumOfVecs();

}
```

I have a couple of codes like the code above where I need iterators in the loop. But I get the error 'invalid controlling predicate'. Is there any way to overcome this?

Thanks in advance

---

By the way I'm using the latest versions of code::blocks and mingw. I'm new to this but I think they support openmp3.0 by default after -fopenmp. The iterator I'm using is list iterator.

Comment: The problem is that the current OpenMP specification doesn't allow the operator "!=". The Intel compiler currently does allow "!=", so there is an example that this can be implemented. In a future OpenMP spec, it will most likely be changed. Until then you are going to be limited to <, <=, >, and >= as the relational operators you can use.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list<T>::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator. Afaik, openmp3 parallel for loop works with random access iterators only (and no !=, as ejd mentioned). Maybe you can use a `std::vector` instead.